# Intellij IDEA scala : unresolved dependencies that can be resolved by sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Idea is unabled to resolve dependencies that can be resolved by `sbt` alone. If I refresh my project in IDEA (`sbt projects / refresh`), I get the following error :

```
[error] (captureArgos/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.reactivemongo#reactivemongo_2.11;0.12.6-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.eu.acolyte#reactive-mongo_2.11;1.0.46-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] (captureArgos/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.reactivemongo#reactivemongo_2.11;0.12.6-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.eu.acolyte#reactive-mongo_2.11;1.0.46-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Aug 21, 2017 2:12:15 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/Users/gbe/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2017.2/sbt.last.log">file:/Users/gbe/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2017.2/sbt.last.log</a>
```

But if I compile the project using only sbt, everything is fine. Why ?

Comment: Did you check "Use SBT shell for build and import" in settings?  If not I'd recommend to enable it, provided that you use a recent SBT version.

Comment: I can't I have unresolved dependencies : `org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;7.0.0+49-9bc0cd21: not found` and `org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;1.2+2-3eadcace: not found`. I can't understand why...If you have any idea, you're welcome !

Comment: What SBT version are you using? Just shooting blind, though, haven't seen this error before.  I suggest to ask Jetbrains support; I understand they are always eager for feedback about this feature.